# print columns names if row equal to value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can i  iterate between rows and print the columns names in one column if the value = 1

```
mydata = [{'a' : '0', 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, {'a' : 1, 'b': 0, 'c':1}, {'a' : '0', 'b': 1, 'c':1}] 
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

a   b   c   Result 
0   1   0   b 
1   0   1   a , c
0   1   1   b , c
```

The result only shows the columns name that are equal to 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `dot`

```
df['New']=df.astype(int).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
df
Out[44]: 
   a  b  c  New
0  0  1  0    b
1  1  0  1  a,c
2  0  1  1  b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing to index the row, and join column names

```
df['new'] = df.eq(1).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x].index), axis = 1)

    a   b   c   new
0   0   1   0   b
1   1   0   1   a, c
2   0   1   1   b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

You an also do this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.set_value(i,'Result',[df.columns[(df == 1).iloc[i]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

More beginners solutions would be

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for key in row.keys():
        print(key if row.get(key) == 1 else None)
```